# Why does multibyte character to char32_t conversion use UTF-8 as the multibyte encoding instead of the locale-specific one?

Tags: c, unicode, encoding, console, mingw-w64

I have been trying to convert Chinese character input from Windows command prompt in Big5 to UTF-8 by first converting the received input to `char32_t` in UTF-32 encoding, then convert it to UTF-8. I've been calling the function `mbtoc32` from `<uchar.h>` to do this job, however it kept sending "Encoding error".

#### The following is the conditions I have encountered:

- Converting the sequence (Big5) to a `wchar_t` representation by `mbstowcs` is successful.
- `mbrtoc32` takes the multibyte sequence as UTF-8, though the locale is not. (Set to `""`, returns *"Chinese (Traditional)_Hong Kong SAR.950"* on my machine)

---

Below is the code I've been writing to try to debug my problem, however no success. It tries to convert the *"香" Chinese character (U+9999)* into the multibyte representation, then tries to convert the Big5 encoding of "香" (0xADBB) into `wchar_t` and `char32_t`. However, converting from multibyte (Big5) to `char32_t` returns encoding error. (In contradictory, inputting the UTF-8 sequence of "香" to `mbrtoc32` does return 0x9999 successfully)

```
#include <uchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

mbstate_t state;
int main(void){
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
    printf("Your locale is: %s\n", setlocale(LC_CTYPE, NULL));
    char32_t chi_c = 0x9999;
    printf("Character U+9999 is 香\n");
    char *mbc = (char *)calloc(32, sizeof(char));
    size_t mb_len;
    mb_len = c32rtomb(mbc, chi_c, &state);
    int i;
    printf("The multibyte representation of U+9999 is:\n");
    // 0xE9A699, UTF-8
    for (i = 0; i < mb_len; i++){
        printf("%#2x\t", *(mbc + i));
    }
    char *src_mbs = (char *)calloc(32, sizeof(char));
    // "香" in Big5 encoding
    *(src_mbs + 0) = 0xad;
    *(src_mbs + 1) = 0xbb;
    wchar_t res_wc;
    mbtowc(&res_wc, src_mbs, 32); // Success, res_wc == 0x9999
    char32_t res_c32;
    mb_len = mbrtoc32(&res_c32, src_mbs, (size_t)3, &state);
    // Returns (size_t)-1, encoding error
    if (mb_len == (size_t)-1){
        perror("Encoding error");
        return errno;
    }
    else {
        printf("\nThe 32-bit character representation of U+9999 is:\n%#x", res_wc);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've also read documentation from [*cppreference.com*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte/mbrtoc32), it said,

> In any case, the multibyte character encoding used by this function is specified by the currently active C locale.

I expect `mbrtoc32` to behave like `mbtowc`, which is converting the character from the locale-specific encoding to **UTF-32** (in this case Big5 to UTF-32).

Is there any solutions to use `mbrtoc32` to convert the multibyte character into `char32_t` without having the "Encoding error"?

*P.S.: I'm using Mingw-64 on Windows 10, compiled with gcc.*

Comment: Could it be as simple as `state` being uninitialized?

Comment: @MarkRansom global variables should be initialized to all zeros

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt should be, but I've learned not to rely on assumptions like that.  Call me paranoid.

Comment: Make sure that you have `__STD_UTF_32__` defined. Technically, without this, the encoding produced by `mbrtoc32` is undefined.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield The macro `__STD_UTF_32__` is defined in `<uchar.h>` in Mingw-64. Here's the code: 
`#ifndef __STDC_UTF_32__
#define __STDC_UTF_32__ 1
#endif`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the problem. The *Mingw-w64* I'm using is expecting all multi-byte string passed to `mbrtoc32` and `c32rtomb` to be in **UTF-8** encoding.

Code for `mbrtoc32`:

```
size_t mbrtoc32 (char32_t *__restrict__ pc32,
         const char *__restrict__ s,
         size_t n,
         mbstate_t *__restrict__ __UNUSED_PARAM(ps))
{
    if (*s == 0)
    {
    *pc32 = 0;
    return 0;
    }

    /* ASCII character - high bit unset */
    if ((*s & 0x80) == 0)
    {
    *pc32 = *s;
    return 1;
    }

    /* Multibyte chars */
    if ((*s & 0xE0) == 0xC0) /* 110xxxxx needs 2 bytes */
    {
    if (n < 2)
        return (size_t)-2;

    *pc32 = ((s[0] & 31) << 6) | (s[1] & 63);
    return 2;
    }
    else if ((*s & 0xf0) == 0xE0) /* 1110xxxx needs 3 bytes */
    {
    if (n < 3)
        return (size_t)-2;

    *pc32 = ((s[0] & 15) << 12) | ((s[1] & 63) << 6) | (s[2] & 63);
    return 3;
    }
    else if ((*s & 0xF8) == 0xF0) /* 11110xxx needs 4 bytes */
    {
    if (n < 4)
        return (size_t)-2;

    *pc32 = ((s[0] & 7) << 18) | ((s[1] & 63) << 12) | ((s[2] & 63) << 6) | (s[4] & 63);
    return 4;
    }

    errno = EILSEQ;
    return (size_t)-1;
}
```

and for `c32rtomb`:

```
size_t c32rtomb (char *__restrict__ s,
         char32_t c32,
         mbstate_t *__restrict__ __UNUSED_PARAM(ps))
{
    if (c32 <= 0x7F) /* 7 bits needs 1 byte */
    {
    *s = (char)c32 & 0x7F;
    return 1;
    }
    else if (c32 <= 0x7FF) /* 11 bits needs 2 bytes */
    {
    s[1] = 0x80 | (char)(c32 & 0x3F);
    s[0] = 0xC0 | (char)(c32 >> 6);
    return 2;
    }
    else if (c32 <= 0xFFFF) /* 16 bits needs 3 bytes */
    {
    s[2] = 0x80 | (char)(c32 & 0x3F);
    s[1] = 0x80 | (char)((c32 >> 6) & 0x3F);
    s[0] = 0xE0 | (char)(c32 >> 12);
    return 3;
    }
    else if (c32 <= 0x1FFFFF) /* 21 bits needs 4 bytes */
    {
    s[3] = 0x80 | (char)(c32 & 0x3F);
    s[2] = 0x80 | (char)((c32 >> 6) & 0x3F);
    s[1] = 0x80 | (char)((c32 >> 12) & 0x3F);
    s[0] = 0xF0 | (char)(c32 >> 18);
    return 4;
    }

    errno = EILSEQ;
    return (size_t)-1;
}
```

both of these functions expected the given multi-byte string to be in UTF-8 without considering the locale settings. Functions [`mbrtoc32`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=wcsmbs/mbrtoc32.c;hb=HEAD) and [`c32rtomb`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=wcsmbs/c32rtomb.c;hb=HEAD) on [*glibc*](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=summary) simply calls their wide character counterpart to convert the characters. As 
wide character convertions are working properly on *Mingw-w64*, I used `mbrtowc` and `wcrtomb` to replace `mbrtoc32` and `c32rtomb` respectively like the way on [*glibc*](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=summary):

```
#include <uchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

mbstate_t state;
int main(void){
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
    printf("Your locale is: %s\n", setlocale(LC_CTYPE, NULL));
    char *src_mbs = "\xad\xbb"; // "香" in Big5 encoding
    char32_t src_c32 = 0x9999; // "香" code point
    unsigned char *r_mbc = (char *)calloc(32, sizeof(char));
    if (r_mbc == NULL){
        perror("Failed to allocate memory");
        return errno;
    }
    size_t mb_len = wcrtomb(r_mbc, (wchar_t)src_c32, &state); // Returns 0xADBB, Big5 of "香", OK
    printf("Character U+9999 is %s, ( ", r_mbc);
    for (int i = 0; i < mb_len; i++){
        printf("%#hhx ", *(r_mbc + i));
    }
    printf(")\n");
    // mb_len = c32rtomb(r_mbc, src_c32, &state); // Returns 0xE9A699, UTF-8 representation of "香", expected Big5
    // printf("\nThe multibyte representation of U+9999 is:\n");
    // for (i = 0; i < mb_len; i++){
    //     printf("%#hhX\t", *(r_mbc + i));
    // }
    char32_t r_c32 = 0;
    // mb_len = mbrtoc32(&r_c32, src_mbs, (size_t)3, &state);
    // Returns (size_t)-1, encoding error
    mb_len = mbrtowc((wchar_t *)&r_c32, src_mbs, (size_t)3, &state); // Returns 0x9999, OK
    if (mb_len == (size_t)-1){
        perror("Encoding error");
        return errno;
    }
    else {
        printf("\nThe 32-bit character representation of U+9999 is:\n%#x", r_c32);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a defect in mingw, I would report this as a bug.